# Javascript compare substring length returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, encryption, encode

I'm trying to produce encrypted data and store them on server then decrypt. I have a problem with `substr`... A case :

The str created by my crypto function:

```
 uÛÀ0ÊydhÖà7yqê}X7hONüRéjÜÉq.NyÖaZÜdGK!Öhy|CGPOyqê}HïchFü.PjÜçêÈöoièféNÜ.... (260 chars)
```

When I try to decrypt this str immediately after creation (in browser):

```
 let name = str.substr(0,25)
 let occup = str.substr(25,35)

 console.log(name+' = '+name.length) -> uÛÀ0ÊydhÖà7yqê}X7hONüRéjÜ = 25
 console.log(occup+' = '+occup.length) -> Éq.NyÖaZÜdGK!Öhy|CGPOyqê}HïchFü.PjÜ = 35
```

If I apply the decrypt algo on each substr the results are those expected.

The crypted str is then sent to the server with Ajax+PHP and written in a `.dat` file.

I use `fetch` to get the crypted data back in browser and try to decrypt it again:

```
 let name = crypt.substr(0,25)
 let occup = str.substr(25,35)

 console.log(name+' = '+name.length) -> uÛÀ0ÊydhÖà7yqê}X7hONüRéj = 25
 console.log(occup+' = '+occup.length) -> ÜÉq.NyÖaZÜdGK!Öhy|CGPOyqê}HïchFü.Pj = 35
```

...but you can count, name got 24 chars instead of 25. The last char of `name` (`Ü`) is now the first of `occup`, which got its 35 cars.

I presume it's an encoding problem on some signs during writing data on server. I try with `substr(0,25)` and `substring(0,25)` but both results are wrong.

Is there a way to solve it

1. when sending data, or
2. when getting str back

?

Comment: Can you show us how you're sending it to the PHP endpoint ?

Comment: let data = ''datuser="+DATUSER;
let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
// get STR
}};
xhr.open('POST','u.php',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");xhr.send(datas);

Comment: PHP : file_put_contents('user.dat',$str);

Comment: I presume that a char in the 25 first (name str) use 2 places instead of 1 but I don't want (if possible) to regex each special char if a better solution exists

Comment: same prob with encodeURI(str) when ajaxing and decodeURI(str) when back

Comment: In chrome if I do `str.substr(0,25)` it gives me `"uÛÀ0ÊydhÖà7yqê}X7hONüRéjÜ"` which has 25 characters. If I ask for `.length` it gives me 25

Comment: yes but as str inside your browser, not coming from PHP server I presume ?

Comment: It really depends of chars. With another name it works.

Comment: Hard to understand: I've finally found a weird solution with extra chars (like [ or / ) putted between parts of string, then once string is loaded form server I simply split these extra chars to retrieve my different substr. 1st part.length is 26 with 25 chars on screen.

Comment: If you need to treat your data as text, then you need to e.g. base 64 encode it. If you treat random binary data as text, you will lose data, because not all bytes are (printable) characters.